# Adafruit_NeoPixel define pin for different setups

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo, adafruit, rgb-led

I am looking for a way of defining multiple pins for my RGB strips. Currently the defined variable is set with the pin within it. This works just fine if I only had one RGB strip connected to the Arduino but I have 4 so I will need to define.

I currently run this code here:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <avr/power.h>

int rgb1 = 18;
int rgb2 = 17;
int LEDs = 11;
int ledFadeTime = 5;

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip1 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LEDs, rgb1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip2 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LEDs, rgb2, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip1.begin();
  strip1.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
  strip2.begin();
  strip2.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  rgbFadeInAndOutStrip1(0, 0, 255, ledFadeTime); // Blue
  rgbFadeInAndOutStrip2(255, 0, 0, ledFadeTime); // red
}

void rgbFadeInAndOutStrip1(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint8_t b = 0; b <255; b++) {
     for(uint8_t i=0; i < strip1.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip1.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
     }

     strip1.show();
     delay(wait);
  };

  for(uint8_t b=255; b > 0; b--) {
     for(uint8_t i = 0; i < strip1.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip1.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
     }
     strip1.show();
     delay(wait);
  };
};

void rgbFadeInAndOutStrip2(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint8_t b = 0; b <255; b++) {
     for(uint8_t i=0; i < strip2.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip2.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
     }

     strip2.show();
     delay(wait);
  };

  for(uint8_t b=255; b > 0; b--) {
     for(uint8_t i = 0; i < strip2.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip2.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
     }
     strip2.show();
     delay(wait);
  };
};
```

Which works when trying out just one out of the 2. But when the LEDs fade out it has a pause (i still see a hint of blue on the strip). If i comment all the code out for the second strip2 and run that, it pulses just fine without the hint of blue or the delay to start bright again.

What could I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: The WS2812 is very sensitive to timing on the data line, so your use of delay() function, which blocks, might be preventing the data stream from updating fast enough. You need need to do this in the "BlinkWithoutDelay" style or eventually you'll run into the situation where the WS2812 does random things because it's waiting for an update, which you've blocked with "delay" - see video... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VZgaJBrZD8

Answer (score 1):

The “hint of blue on the strip” is a consequence of your second loop in `rgbFadeInAndOutStrip1()` ending with the test `b > 0`.  Because of that, the last `strip1.setPixelColor()` call sets the color to (0,0,1), a faint blue, instead of (0,0,0), off.  Here is some revised code that works ok:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
enum { rgbPin1=8, rgbPin2=7, LEDcount=11, ledFadeTime=5};

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip1 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LEDcount, rgbPin1);
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip2 = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LEDcount, rgbPin2);

void setup() {
  strip1.begin();
  strip1.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
  strip2.begin();
  strip2.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  rgbFadeInAndOutStrip1(0, 0, 255, ledFadeTime); // Blue
  rgbFadeInAndOutStrip2(255, 0, 0, ledFadeTime); // red
}

void fadeStrip(Adafruit_NeoPixel *strip, int bval, int bdir, uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint8_t b=0; b<255; ++b) {
    bval += bdir;
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<strip->numPixels(); ++i) {
      strip->setPixelColor(i, red * bval/255, green * bval/255, blue * bval/255);
    }
    strip->show();
    delay(wait);
  } 
}

void rgbFadeInAndOutStrip1(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t wait) {
  fadeStrip(&strip1, -1, 1,   red, green, blue, wait);
  fadeStrip(&strip1, 255, -1, red, green, blue, wait);
}

void rgbFadeInAndOutStrip2(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t wait) {
  fadeStrip(&strip2, -1, 1,   red, green, blue, wait);
  fadeStrip(&strip2, 255, -1, red, green, blue, wait);
}
```

Note, since I ran tests on an Uno rather than a Leonardo, I attached pixel strings to pins 7 and 8 rather than 17 and 18.  I used `enum` to define constants, rather than declaring constants as variables, and factored some common code into functions rather than reduplicating it.

Following is another program (which I call neocycle6) you can use to test two strips.  Note, it only counts colors down to 1 rather than 0 because I like the effect of leftover pixels glowing faintly.  Also note: the round boards I used have only 7 LEDs each, so I set `PixelCount` to 7, not 11; this uses pins 7 and 8, not 17 and 18; I don't drive the brightness beyond 77 since the LEDs are so bright anyway; and it doesn't have an
`#include <avr/power.h>` statement, which you can add if needed.

```
// Drive 2 sets of 7 ea. WS2812 NeoPixels through sets of colors.
// jw 11 September 2015  
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

// Select pin# connected to NeoPixels strand, and number of NeoPixels.
enum { PixelPinA=7, PixelPinB=8, PixelCount=7 };
// Create a NeoPixels device structure
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixelA = Adafruit_NeoPixel(PixelCount, PixelPinA);
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixelB = Adafruit_NeoPixel(PixelCount, PixelPinB);

void setup() {
  byte i, j=0;
  pixelA.begin();               // Init. NeoPixel data structure
  pixelB.begin();               // Init. NeoPixel data structure
}

uint8_t c=1, d=1, p=0, v=1;
void loop() {
  c += d;
  if (c>76)
    d = -1;                     // Go down when done going up
  else {
    if (c<2) {                  // Set up for next pixel
      d = 1; p = (p+1)%PixelCount;
      if (!p) ++v;              // Rotate the weights to next color
    }
  }

  pixelA.setPixelColor(p, c*(v&1), c*((v&2)/2), c*((v&4)/4));
  pixelB.setPixelColor(p, c*((v&2)/2), c*(v&1), c*((v&4)/4));
  pixelA.show();               // Show updated colors
  pixelB.show();               // Show updated colors
  delay(9 + 300/c);            // Ramp small numbers more slowly
}
```